# "npm install" for OpenMCT giving lots of errors

Tags: node.js, npm

I was going through the [Tutorials](https://nasa.github.io/openmct/getting-started/) for NASA's [OpenMCT](https://github.com/nasa/openmct) mission control framework and trying to install  on my macbook (OS X El Capitan).  I have installed `node.js v4.5.0 LTS`. npm version is 2.15.9. Every time I try `npm install` it is showing me the following errors and warnings.

```
npm WARN engine karma-cli@0.0.4: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"4.5.0","npm":"2.15.9"})
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.2.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/jscs/-/jscs-2.11.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 400

> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.12 install /Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './internal/applyEach'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async/applyEach.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated wrench@1.5.9: wrench.js is deprecated! You should check out fs-extra (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) for any operations you were using wrench for. Thanks for all the usage over the years.
\
> node-sass@3.8.0 install /Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at /Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-46/binding.node

> fsevents@1.0.14 install /Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall /Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"/Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-46/binding.node" exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.12 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.12 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs-prebuilt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs phantomjs-prebuilt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs-prebuilt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Dhrubo/git/openmct/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating minimatch fixed the problem. Run following command.

```
npm update minimatch
```

then run `npm install`